# set array values to zero in a mex cuda function

Tags: arrays, cuda, mex

I am writing a MEX function containing CUDA code and in the Host function I need to reset all array `A` values to float `0.0`. This seems to work by destroying and re-creating the array:

```
    mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(A);
    A = mxGPUCreateGPUArray(1, &dims, mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL, MX_GPU_INITIALIZE_VALUES);
```

Is there a more natural/elegant way to achieve the same result?

Comment: If you want to do it **in a mex cuda function** you should be able to use [`cudaMemset`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gf7338650f7683c51ee26aadc6973c63a).

Comment: I forgot to mention that my array A is a 3D array of size [K,K,K]. I have tried using cudaMemset(A, 0.0, (K * K * K) * sizeof(float)); but this returns a bunch of errors upon execution

Comment: I'm quite convinced that `cudaMemset` could be used.  A more complete description would probably be needed to explain why it is not working in your case.

Comment: As can be seen in the documentation Robert linked, cudaMemset expects an integer as parameter, not the `0.0` float you're passing in (but don't worry too much: a floating point with value `0.0` actually has `0` as binary representation). Also mxGPUCreateGPUArray returns an mxGPUArray object, which should contain a pointer to your array (get it using (mxGPUGetData)[http://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/mxgpugetdata.html]). I'm not sure how MEX implements 3D arrays in the backend though - there's specific memset functions for dealing with multi-dimension padded (pitched) arrays.

Comment: To add to that, the floating point error should be thrown at compiling stage, not execution (I've actually never had the chance to work with MEX, so I'm not sure how helpful my comment is).

Comment: @MarijnS95 right, one must pass the device pointer d_A instead of the object A. The correct function which worked is: cudaMemset(d_A, 0, (K * K * K)*sizeof(float));
Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :). Anyway, how did you get d_A? Is that what mxGPUGetData returns? Then I can add that to the answer for future reference.

Comment: exactly, the device pointer is d_A = (float *)(mxGPUGetData(A));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cudaMemset` expects a device pointer, whereas `mxGPUCreateGPUArray` returns an `mxGPUobject`. According to the documentation, one should be able to get this pointer using [`mxGPUGetData`](http://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/mxgpugetdata.html). Also, the `value` parameter needs to be of type int, instead of the float you're giving it. Luckily a floating point value of 0.0 corresponds to a binary (/integer) representation of `0`.

(question 'migrated' from comment)